# How to create Sharepoint ONET file

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I was trying to find any tool that I can use to create **ONET** file from the existing SharePoint site. Unfortunately wasn't able to find. Does anybody know anything about that? There should be something besides of manual way to do that... Any MS solutions, third party tools?

Comment: Doesn't the existing site already _have_ an ONET.XML file? You could copy it.

Answer (score 0):

As John Saunders is alluding, the simplest approach would be to let SharePoint create it for you. It's not exactly sitting in the site though; you can't just open the site in SharePoint Designer & grab it - but there is a way to get it:

1. Save the site as a Site Template (with or without content, doesn't matter - but without will be faster/smaller)
2. Download the STP/WSP from the Site Template (SP2007)/Solutions (SP2010/13) Gallery to your desktop
3. Change the file extension to .CAB
4. Use an archive tool (i.e. 7-zip) to unpack the CAB file
5. Within the unpacked CAB you will see a folder whose name will be the original name of your Site Template + "WebTemplate"
6. Within that folder will be a sub-folder whose name is just the original name of your Site Template
7. Within that folder is the ONet.xml file